# Timeout error when doing a search in a web page using protractor

Tags: timeout, webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I've done a lot of searching on the web for this issue and haven't found a solution.  I am using Protractor to drive a web test and perform a search query in the UI.  The results take a while to come back (approximately 8 minutes).  I added the 'allScriptsTimeout' argument to my config file for 10 minutes, but it doesn't seem to help.  The timeout error appears every time at the 5 minute mark, regardless.  Any ideas on what else I can try in order to bypass this seemingly hard-set timeout?  The error I am getting is this (partial):

```
ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.988
(Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNI
NG: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 300.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: dc370ac53e9afba8a2f69e82e0c42d0b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
....
```

Comment: a UI query taking 8 mins is probably the worst user experience ever! There's something wrong there mate, why not try a SQL performance question instead? Anyway, I provided an answer below that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to also specify `setScriptTimeout` and `pageLoadTimeout` to 20 minutes like this:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60*20*1000);
// Warning: Below option is not supported in Safari webdriver
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60*20*1000);
```

Comment: Yeah, we're working on improving this, but in the meantime I need to capture the data and allow the script to finish.  The good news is, your suggestion worked.  I'm going to test to see if the pageLoadTimeout line helped...I didn't have that originally.  Thanks again, elgalu!

Comment: Confirmed that the pageLoadTimeout line was the key.  That single line solved everything for me.  Thx!

Comment: Awesome! I'm so glad I helped :)